# How to set up the From field in sendmail?

Tags: php, linux, unix, ubuntu, sendmail

I've got the simple code snippet

```php
mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');
```

My server is on Ubuntu. So the `php.ini` is

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F "Test" -f "example@mysite.test"
```

My `/etc/hosts` is

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost pm
```

I'm receiving emails from `www-data@localhost.localdomain`. I don't want to set the `From:` header explicitely when call `mail`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use the `sendmail_from` php.ini option?

Comment: @Barmar It's marked as `For Win32 only`. But anyway I've tried it before I made this post.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the whole option value in quotes? I.e. `"/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F Test -f example@mysite.test"` Usually quotes are used to delimit a string. At least the [documentation on `parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) states that strings with whitespace should be quoted.

Comment: @Lukas `-f` is now shown in emails, `-F` is ignored. My path: "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -FTest -fexample@mysite.test"

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the right order, I'm writing down my comment again as a regular answer.

In PHP's INI files, string values that contain non-aalphanumeric characters have to be quoted with double quotes (`"`).
This is described in the [`parse_ini_file()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), though it seems to apply to PHP's internal (configuration) INI parsing as well.

Hence, your INI line should be:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F Test -f example@mysite.test"
```

You can optionally quote the values of the sendmail parameters (note the escape sequence):

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F \"Test\" -f \"example@mysite.test\""
```

Now, `sendmail` will generate this `From:` header:

```
From: "Test" <example@mysite.test>
```